# Hide a row in RDLC report without disabling the code execution

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

How could I hide a row in a .rdlc report without disabling the code execution for this row?

Comment: Did you get what you needed out of the responses below?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Visibility.Hidden` property. Click on the Detail row handle to select the entire detail row, expand the Visibility property and enter an expression in the Hidden property that will hide the row. For example, if you want to hide the row when MyField is zero, you'd enter:

```
=IIF(Fields!MyField.Value = 0, True, False)
```

Comment: My problem is that I have a report with thousands of rows and I don't have the time to do this manually. Is there some way to modify all visibility from code?

Comment: You mean you have thousands of detail rows? Just multiselect them - click the row handle for the top one, hold down shift and click the row handle for the bottom one to select them all, then enter your visibility expression.

Comment: Yes, but that will only set the same expression for every row, correct? What I have is two columns, A and B, and each row's visibility is based on a value appearing in each cell for column B. So row 1 should be visible only if B1 has a value, row 2 if B2 has a value, etc. So, each row's expression must be different.

Comment: If there was a function to reference a column's cells using indexes, I'd be golden!

Comment: That sounds doable. Maybe make a new question with your problem in full detail and perhaps we can find a solution.

Comment: Okay, hold one second

Comment: Link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769524/is-there-a-quick-way-to-set-a-visiblity-expression-for-many-rows-in-a-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Use a table filter. The data will be extracted the filtered after excecution.

However I don't see the need for this unless.