# Is there a quick way to set a visiblity expression for many rows in a SQL Server Report Services RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a report with many tables (tablixes?), in which I need to hide all rows that don't have a value in the 2nd column:

[image]

I can do this by right clicking on each row

[image]

and setting an expression for the visibility of the row that depends on a value appearing in the field of the 2nd column, e.g.

```
=IIF((Fields!MyField4.Value = ""), True, False)
```

But the problem is that my report has over 1000 of these rows! It will take a very long time given that each field has a specific name! I can modify the Xml, but this will also take a while. I am currently writing some code, which uses XDocument, to achieve this.

Are there any faster ways that anyone can think of? Maybe something from the designer, or some VB code? Everywhere on the internet seems to suggest right clicking one row at a time.

Comment: Why don't you filter those values from the dataset?

Comment: Is there a way to do this on multiple values, quickly? Googling just get's me all of the visibility questions I've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

In the Designer, select all of the rows (using your Shift or Ctrl key), and use the Properties pane in VS/BIDS to change them all at once. There is a Hidden property there, and you can choose Expression from the dropdown in it. From there, you can apply the IIF to all rows.

Of course, I am assuming all of the visibility is based on the exact same expression for each row. If not, then the answer is no. Unless, you want to start doing some copy/paste stuff in the RDL XML, which I do not recommend.

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking that XML approach. It's really not that bad, you just need to make backups.

Comment: Interesting, I would have assumed that the XML route would be quite painful. Any chance of changing the design of the report to make this not a problem in the future?

Comment: Well I've been going through a lot of pain for sure, but I mostly have a grasp of what's going on, as opposed to say, modifying the designer.cs file of a windows form, which seems to mess up every time for me.

Comment: To answer your other question, no, I still don't see a way to make it not a problem. Textbox cells are assigned names automatically, Textbox1, Textbox2, etc. So this means every expression has to be different for every row.

Comment: Good luck with all of this!

Comment: I got it to work using XDocument. Not sure I'll post an answer to my own question yet.

Comment: If you think it is a viable answer to the question, post it. I am sure someone will find it useful.